# How can I let docker container use codebuild IAM authentication to deploy to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-codebuild

I am running CI/CD in codebuild project and I have configured a role for codebulid project to allow it to deploy resources e.g. lambda to AWS account.

But when I run the deploy command from docker container in the codebuild project, I got this error:

`AWS provider credentials not found. Learn how to set up AWS provider credentials in our docs here: <http://slss.io/aws-creds-setup>.`

I have searched that people says to use env var or aws credential profile. But my script is running from codebuild project with IAM authentication. How can I pass it to docker container?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would not give `Codebuild` direct access to modify resources, you can easily separate that out via a separate role to deploy stuff and make sure you have added the necessary permissions to assume the role. Below is the approach recommended by AWS.

```yaml
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      nodejs: 8
    commands:
      - ASSUME_ROLE_ARN="arn:aws:iam::$account_id:role/Secretassumerole"
      - TEMP_ROLE=`aws sts assume-role --role-arn $ASSUME_ROLE_ARN --role-session-name test`
      - export TEMP_ROLE
      - echo $TEMP_ROLE
      - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo "${TEMP_ROLE}" | jq -r '.Credentials.AccessKeyId')
      - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo "${TEMP_ROLE}" | jq -r '.Credentials.SecretAccessKey')
      - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo "${TEMP_ROLE}" | jq -r '.Credentials.SessionToken')
      - echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      - echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
      - echo $AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build --build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --build-arg AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --build-arg AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
```

Inside `Dockefile`

```
FROM amazonlinux:latest
RUN yum -y install aws-cli 
ARG AWS_DEFAULT_REGION 
ARG AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
ARG AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
ARG AWS_SESSION_TOKEN 
RUN echo $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION 
RUN echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID 
RUN echo $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY 
RUN echo $AWS_SESSION_TOKEN 
RUN aws sts get-caller-identity 
RUN aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id tutorials/AWSExampleSecret
```

[How do I pass temporary credentials for AssumeRole into the Docker runtime with AWS CodeBuild?](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/codebuild-temporary-credentials-docker/)

OR

If you still wanna use the `CodeBuild` IAM permissions then you can parse the call to metadata service in `buildspec.yml` for your `Codebuild` project which will give you the credentials of your
`Codebuild IAM Service Role`, eventually being passed to `docker build` command in a similar manner as above. Or if you wish you can store that in a credentials file and share them with the docker environment, where you can run commands by providing the profile.

```yaml
version: 0.2
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - TOKEN=$(curl http://169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI)
      - echo $TOKEN
      - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$(echo "${TOKEN}" | jq -r '.AccessKeyId')
      - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$(echo "${TOKEN}" | jq -r '.SecretAccessKey')
      - export AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$(echo "${TOKEN}" | jq -r '.SessionToken')
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build --build-arg AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID --build-arg AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY --build-arg AWS_SESSION_TOKEN=$AWS_SESSION_TOKEN
```

This will give you the credentials:

```json
{
  "RoleArn": "AQICAHi8hGr15WsKx4aqJ3PRJImmR37T8bWHAVZQA8s9Lug",
  "AccessKeyId": "ASIA2WXKNDTKPASDADRT",
  "SecretAccessKey": "***",
  "Token": "IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjENH//////////wEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJ",
  "Expiration": "2021-03-05T10:02:01Z"
}
```

Comment: I have read through this but the problem is that I have to create a access key and secret. I would like to use IAM authentication.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao I didnt get what you mean by `IAM Authentication`  then? `IAM Authentication` via a role, user or something else?

Comment: I mean use IAM role as the authentication method rather than AccessKey and Secret.

Comment: @JoeyYiZhao this is the answer about, where did I miss, first one is via a separate `IAM Role` and second is where you have amended the necessary permissions directly for your `CodeBuild` role for deploying resources. You can't consume an `IAM Role` directly you need to assume it, and get the necessary credentials and then use those for doing operations.

Comment: yes you are right. And sorry I mis-understood. accepted your answer. thanks.

Comment: This has been extremely useful to solve [a similar problem I had](https://github.com/bep/s3deploy/issues/340). Just a minor thing: do you by any chance have a typo in the json path `jq -r '.SessionToken'`? I had to tweak it to `jq -r '.Token'` (just like you show in the full json underneath).

Comment: `http://169.254.170.2 ` is this static?

Answer (score 2):

A variation on the second of samtoddler's answers:

```
docker build --build-arg AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI=$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI --build-arg AWS_REGION=$AWS_REGION
```

and in the docker file:

```
ARG AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI
ARG AWS_REGION
```

Basically CodeBuild/Docker are clever enough to do the commands Sam has in the install section automatically :)

Comment: Is it AWS_REGION or AWS_DEFAULT_REGION?

Comment: AWS_REGION works. I don't know exactly what AWS_DEFAULT_REGION is so can't say what the effect would be.